# Find and replace String with a substring result

Tags: java, strings

I was asked this recently, and I couldn't figure out the best way. We are trying to replicate Google's search results where the search terms are bolded (using a b tag) in the results.

```
Input                       Terms               Output
The search is cool          {sea}               The <b>sea</b>rch is cool
```

Originally, I thought this was pretty easy:

```
String results(String input, String[] terms)
{
   for(String term : terms)
   {
      input = input.replace(term, "<b>" + term + "</b>");
   }

   return input;
}
```

However, this isn't correct. For example:

```
Input                       Terms               Output
The search is cool          {sea, search}       The <b>search</b> is cool
```

I struggled to figure out the best way to approach this. Obviously we can no longer find and replace immediately. I played around with using a `Map<Integer,String>` where the key is the index returned by `input.indexOf(term)` and the value is the term, but this seemed potentially unnecessary. Any improvements?

```
public String results(String input, String[] terms)
{
   Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
   for(String term : terms)
   {
      int index = input.indexOf(term);
      if(index >= 0)//if found
      {
          String value = map.get(index);
          if(value == null || value.length() < term.length())//use the longer term
              map.put(index, term);
      }


   }

   for(String term: map.values())
   {
       input = input.replace(term, "<b>" + term + "</b>");
   }

   return input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Regex for this, with greedy matches so that nested results like your example above would only match the outer string.

So with your example here:

```
Input                       Terms               Output
The search is cool          {sea, search}       The <b>search</b> is cool
```

A Regex pattern of `search|sea` could be derived from the search terms, and only 'search' would be matched. Note that the longest term will need to first for this to work as desired.

```
String results(String input)
{
 String retVal = input.replaceAll("search|sea", "<b>$1</b>")

 return input;
}
```

I think this should be close to what you need, but I havn't had time to test and check. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just FYI - greedy is not what you think it is, I don't think: http://fiddle.re/9bmb4

Answer (score 0):

The second version looks fine. Anyway, two other quick ideas:

1. Consider replacing only complete words (substrings which has whitespace before and after).
2. Sort the term list by length (descending) and ABC then replace every occurrence only once. [`StringUtils.replaceEach`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) supports that.

   ```
   String input = "The sea search is cool";
   String[] terms = new String[] { "search", "sea" };
   String[] replacementList = new String[] { "<b>search</b>", "<b>sea</b>" };
   String output = StringUtils.replaceEach(input, terms, replacementList);
   System.out.println(output);
   ```

   The output is the following:

   ```
   String input = "The sea search is cool";
   String[] terms = new String[] { "search", "sea" };
   ```

Comment: Words can be delimited by whitespace, but also by punctuation or the start/end of the string.